# SPWebService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied - How to use it in a proper way?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have created a SharePoint web part with creates and updates SharePoint Timer Jobs automatically. The web part runs from the content web applications and not from the central admin.

I've learnt that MSFT has made some minor changes in updating `SPPersistedObject`. So I'm getting Access Denied while calling `Update()`.

But here are my questions -

1. I understood that we cannot set
   `SPWebService.RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied
   = false` from the code running in content web applications. Is there a
   STSADM command for it other than
   powershell?
2. I can turn it off from a FARM
   feature but is that secure if I
   don't turn it off immediately?

What is the best way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't believe so - you need to set the property from code running in CA or set it from a Powershell script.
2. I honestly am not sure what security loophole Microsoft was trying to close with this one - but I'm also not a security guru - in fact quite the opposite.

My suggestion is to disable the security feature, do what you need to do, then turn it back on.  Since it's a very simple Powershell script (or farm feature receiver if that's your thing) it should be pretty simple to disable/reenable each time you need to do something (which hopefully won't be that often anyway).

Comment: We cannot do it programmatically. Or can we?

Comment: If you're trying to do it programmatically, you should perform the operation from CA.  Otherwise, you'll need to create a service that runs as the spfarm account, such as a web service, that will perform your operation.  Remember - even the STSADM or PowerShell commands you'd run to disable the security feature need to be run by the spfarm account (or another user with the proper access).